# html css javascript canvas isn't visible on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I've been trying to make something move in the background of my website using canvas, like a object or just lines that randomly appear at slightly different speed and size. But my background is in the way of the canvas I think. Did I do something wrong, or is it in the way of my background? Im very new to coding, so please be patient with me. Thanks!

thanks

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
/*gare kleuren achtergrond*/
body {
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab, #33D7FF);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
/*witte div*/
#div1 {

    width: 101.5%;
    height: 1000px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-right: 220px;
   padding: 50px, 50px, 50px, 50px;
   background-color:white;
   border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
 }

#div1 h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#div1 p{
    color: black;
    font-family: lucida console, monospace;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    color: black;
    font-family: lucida console, monospace;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.woord {
    transition:0.5s;
    border: 0px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: -10px;


    margin-bottom: -22px;
}

li{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: lucida console, monospace;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;

}
a{
    transition: ease-in-out  .2s;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

}
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:hover{
    border: 1px solid;
    zoom: 1.1;


}


.nav{
    border:1px solid;
    border-width:1px;
    height: 64px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 1000px;
   margin-left: 220px;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
Javascript

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 40){
      $(".woord").css({"opacity" : "0"})
    }
    else {
      $(".woord").css({"opacity" : "1"})
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="gaar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="woord">

        <h1>website</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
       </div> 
       <div id="div1">
        <h1>main</h1>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="biografie">Biografie</a></li>
            <li><a href="fotos">fotos</a></li>
            <li><a href="heuristiek">heuristiek</a></li>
            <li><a href="buienradar">buienradar</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>   
        <p>hoi</p>
        <p>dit is mijn website</br>over mijzelf </p>

       </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you open up the web inspector and look at the network requests for the JS and CSS, do you see the correct content types? Are you getting HTTP 200s or are there 40X errors, 50X errors or 30X redirects? Is there content coming in for those requests?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. However, i am very new to coding, I do not understand anything you just asked. If I inspect the page it doesn't say anything, no errors or logs

Comment: When you pull up the inspector and open the network tab, do you see a list of requests?

Comment: It just gives me a list of the files that make the website

Answer (score 0):

(Edited once I realized I misread the original question)

So the`BODY` element is going to be the root of everything visible on your document, so you're not going to get anything "behind" that tag, since everything else is considered a child of it.

If you want something to be behind "everything," you give it a `z-index` of `-1`. That will place it behind everything thats got a z-index set, and everything that's got the default index of `0`. Note that for z-index to have an effect, your element **must** have absolute, fixed, relative or sticky positioning applied.

and if you want it to be visible, ensure anything that appears in front of it is at least partially transparent.

```css
.behind {
  /* may also be absolute, sticky, or relative */
  position: fixed;
  
  /* Put this element behind anything with a higher z-index */
  z-index: -1;
  
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/408/287);
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

h1, p {
  
  /* 100% opaque */
  /*background-color: white;*/
  
  /* 100% transparency */
  /*background-color: transparent;*/
  
  /* 50% transparency */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  /* Nothing is ever actually behind the BODY tag. */
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="behind"></div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales vehicula nulla vitae eleifend. Donec facilisis ligula a lectus tincidunt sagittis. Morbi libero diam, mattis eget tristique ut, tincidunt ut orci. Curabitur vulputate libero at interdum
    vulputate. Quisque tincidunt, sapien quis dapibus accumsan, nulla urna ultrices risus, vel facilisis orci ex id odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus finibus tincidunt sem quis
    fermentum. Donec nec tellus eu dui auctor blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec malesuada diam orci, vitae pulvinar odio tincidunt id. Nam interdum, dolor eu consectetur suscipit, enim eros tempor orci, sit amet ullamcorper ipsum erat id risus. Integer
    finibus nisl vel risus interdum maximus. Cras id nulla ut arcu lacinia aliquet sit amet at arcu. Vestibulum scelerisque velit imperdiet leo aliquet, ultricies accumsan turpis faucibus. Cras pulvinar tempus ipsum, et tempor sapien bibendum semper.
    Morbi bibendum placerat nisl.</p>

  <p>Etiam placerat libero neque, ac imperdiet orci rutrum auctor. Morbi nec commodo justo. Fusce diam lorem, molestie vitae tortor id, vulputate lobortis urna. Aliquam id mauris ligula. Ut posuere tellus ac laoreet pellentesque. Phasellus mollis, felis
    sit amet bibendum condimentum, dui risus feugiat quam, ac porttitor dolor mi non mauris. Duis commodo imperdiet tortor, id consequat dolor. Nullam non ullamcorper tellus, eget aliquam nisl. Nunc sed purus eget elit efficitur ornare blandit ut nunc.
    Nam finibus iaculis ante, ut suscipit massa venenatis sed. Nullam porta, arcu vitae eleifend gravida, diam orci vulputate magna, in lacinia odio odio non tellus. Duis pretium eget diam vitae auctor. Aliquam cursus urna leo, ac vehicula quam posuere
    ac. Etiam in quam justo.</p>

  <p>Nullam dictum gravida orci, quis mollis tortor placerat at. Mauris justo diam, iaculis quis maximus vitae, tincidunt et nisl. Nullam venenatis eros risus, a facilisis elit tincidunt dictum. Suspendisse mi elit, lacinia vel elit lobortis, gravida pharetra
    dolor. Curabitur quis tincidunt diam. Nulla ligula eros, viverra eu nisi et, suscipit blandit sem. Nullam egestas ante vitae quam hendrerit, quis vestibulum nibh sodales. Quisque in dolor viverra, condimentum tortor ut, bibendum ante. Fusce commodo
    mi vel fringilla vehicula. Aliquam mauris leo, feugiat eu varius nec, ornare vel nibh.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My list looks a lot smaller than that, I work on a Mac laptop so maybe that's different? I don't see a red file though.

Comment: Do you see your CSS and JS files in the list?

Comment: yes, and as far as I can see neither is red/ blocked

Comment: I added another image to the post above, if you select the CSS file, do you see the expected file's content on the right side, like above?

Comment: Yes, it appears the same as when I view it in visual studio code

Comment: Oh, sorry! I think I got my wires crossed. For some reason I thought it wasn't loading at all! Have you tried using `background-color:transparent;` ?

Comment: Haha, no problem. Where should I use that? should I put it in the body? What I've tried it doesn't work.

Comment: Let me clear out this answer and I'll put together a little example of how things could be laid out.

Comment: I just heavily edited my post with some more helpful information. Let me know if the example makes things clear.

Comment: So I've tried putting  z-index: -1;  in the body part, but it still doesn't show the line that the canvas should create

Comment: When I run your example above, I see a canvas with a single diagonal line off to the left of the page, is that not what you're expecting to see?

Comment: yes, that was the point. But I can't see it myself, I copied the code In case I made a typo somewhere but I still can't see it. Also, do you only see the canvas? Or does it include the whole website

Comment: Here is what I see, I've darkened the image and highlighed the area where the canvas is visible:

https://i.imgur.com/vTONonf.png

Comment: Are you on mobile? maybe its only visible on mobile. On my desktop it shows the same, except it doesn't show the ball and the line

Comment: This is how it looks unedited: https://i.imgur.com/9VuAMVm.png

Comment: For some reason I cannot see the line when I try it myself, could that be because of some settings perhaps?

Comment: I can select it, it does have a hitbox, but I can't actually see it

Comment: What browser are you using? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reaction. I use safari, and it does not give any error as far as I can see

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Are you able to see the canvas element in your inspector? What happens if you try to fill the canvas in with a solid color?